# Samba intermittently timing out on writes to a ZFS share

Tags: debian, samba, zfs

I'm experiencing an odd problem on a file server intermittently failing when writing files.  The problem occurs when I try to write a number of files from a (Windows 7) client at once.  Intermittently, but relatively often, one of the writes will hang.  It may take as long as 30 seconds for the Windows program to come back.  Access to the SMB share from the Windows shell will also sometimes result in a progress bar until the other program comes out of its freeze.  Other users have reported problems at the same time this happens suggesting it is smbd of the ZFS filesystem that is frozen rather than the Windows client.

Errors include:

- "file cannot be opened for writing"
- "unable to access network location"

System config

- OpenMediaVault 0.5.38 (Debian Squeeze variant)
- samba 3.5.6
- zfs 0.6.2
- 2x3GB WD Red SATA drives in zfs mirrored configuration, no L2ARC or separate ZIL
- not shared using the native ZFS SMB support, but in the standard way using smb.conf

Any suggestions as to what this might be or how to debug it would be most welcome.  There are no errors reported in the samba logs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the same using other filesystem? If this doesn't occur on ext3/4, report a but go ZFS maintainers because it seems like bug.

ZFS is fresh software on linux.
What way do you use ZFS? As native or by FUSE ? Assign this information to bug report.
When you use FUSE version, you can use native, try URL:  http://zfsonlinux.org/debian.html
Of course not all works properly, but the most of native bugs is common to fuse version.

I can't remember, but I think I saw you problem described somewhere on zfslinux.org website.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  It's native ZFS using kernel modules (not FUSE).  Because of the way the system is set up, it's difficult for me to test it on a non-ZFS drive unfortunately.  I will have a look at the page you mentioned though.